# Problem with workflow

Tags: workflow, formula

i need workflow when status from s1 to s10 changes into one of status d1 to d10, to send email alert to user. if status comes from t7 to d1 or from d1 to s5 (example) workflow don't need to do anything. I will attach a picture how that should look a like, and code I already made.

[image]

Code:

```
AND( ISCHANGED(Disposition_Type__c), 

OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "ACR-AWAITING CREDIT REPORT (S)"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-ISC-UNQUALIFIED LEAD"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-ISC- Invalid Contact Detail"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-ACR-CUSTOMER DECLINES"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-CO SIGNER FOUND"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-CR-UNQUALIFIED LEAD"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-U-UNQUALIFIED LEAD"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-AW-CUSTOMER DECLINE - RATE"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-AW-CUSTOMER DECLINE"
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-INVOICE CANCELLED"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-ISC-NOT INTERESTED"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-EXTERNAL COLLECTIONS"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-AW-CUSTOMER DECLINE"),
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-AWC-CUSTOMER DECLINE"),
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-AWC-CUSTOMER DECLINE"),
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-AWSC-CUSTOMER DECLINE- RATE"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "DL-AWSC-CUSTOMER DECLINE"),

ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c , "")), 



OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 1"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 2"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 3"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 4"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 5"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 6"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 7"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 8"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 9"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 10"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 11"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 12"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 13"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 14"), 
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c ), "ISC-CALLED 15") 

))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

This is my custom statues but you can watch it like s1----s10 and like t1-----t10

Comment: What's your specific question?, where are you facing the issue?

Comment: It's working good some part. When i change it from ISC to DL, but when i change from some other status to DL, it sends email again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `OR` syntax works (note [the syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) is `OR(logical1, logical2...)`), but there is a better way:

```
2 = CASE(
    Disposition_Type__c,
    "ACR-AWAITING CREDIT REPORT (S)", 1,
    "DL-ISC-UNQUALIFIED LEAD", 1,
    // etc.
    0
) + CASE(
    PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c),
    "ISC-CALLED 1", 1,
    "ISC-CALLED 2", 1,
    // etc.
    0
)
```

---

If you want to make it work with `OR` syntax, your compile size will be a *lot* higher, but it would be simpler to just use two `OR` clauses:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(Disposition_Type__c),,
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c, "..."),
        ISPICKVAL(Disposition_Type__c, "...")
        // etc
    ),
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c), "..."),
        ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Disposition_Type__c), "...")
        // etc
    )
)
```

You're nesting them, and because of that you haven't grouped them quite how you thought you did.